# Attributes: Access Designation

Tags: c#, oop, private, public, private-members

While I was refering to a book , I got the following statements:

> When a data type or method is defined as public , Other Objects can directly access it. When a data type or method is defined as private , only the specific object can access it.

Now this is really confusing. Public and Private are Access Specifiers which only define the scope of a attribute or method.

Why object is mixed with access specifiers? Does object has to do any thing with public , private or protected apart from the fact that if some thing is defined as public then objects too will be able to access irespective of the scope

Answer (score 1):

This is not a scope question but an access limitation modifier.  If you declare a function as private that means only that class can call that function.

Public: 
   Any one can call these functions 
Private: 
   Only that class and the refection engine 
Protected: 
   Only that class and its derived member
Internal: 
   Public to all the classes in that assembly

A small ex

```
public class A
{
    public int x;
    protected int y;
    private int z;
}

public class B : A
{
    public int CallPro()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public int CallPriv()
    {
        return z; //error 
    }

}

static void Main()
{
    A oa;
    oa.x; //Fine
    oa.y; //Error
    oa.z; //Error


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Public and Private are Access Specifiers which only define the scope
>   of a attribute or method.

And that defines the behaviour of the object. Hence the access specifiers are important for the object. Imagine if you have a facade kind of object, you don't want to expose all the details of the operation, rather you want a simple public interface (eg, Save() method) to be exposed for the consumers. That's why you have to consider the specifiers for objects.

```
public class CustomerFacade()
{
public bool Save(Customer c)
{
    VerifyCustomer(c);
// lots of other steps which the caller does not need to know
    SaveorUpdateCustomer(c);
    }
    private void VerifyCustomer(Customer c)
    {
    }
    private void SaveorUpdateCustomer(Customer c)
    {
    }
    }

public class CustomerController()
{
public bool Save(Customer c)
{
return new CustomerFacade().Save(c);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It will be clearer if you have a code snippet for the same